# Is there any way to limit the number of connected JS clients in PubNub conditionally to prevent bill shocks or attacks?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

This is how the PubNub JS API is initialised:

```
var PUBNUB_demo = PUBNUB.init({
subscribe_key: 'Your Subscribe Key Here'
});
```

Obviously, I have to expose the subscribe key to the user since this is Javascript.

PubNub bills on the number of connected IP addresses. So, what prevents a malicious user from using the subscription key and making queries over 1000s of proxies to give me a bill shock or cause me to reach my max client limit?

Is there any way around this possible problem?

Comment: Hi there, yes indeed you need to contact your account manager and ask for limiters to be enabled.

Comment: Do you require that visitors to your site register or is it just anyone can come in and use your site which includes hitting PubNub?